# Or criteria - Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

i have a hibernate class:

```
class student{
string name;
int roll;
}
```

while fetching records i have a requirement where i need to fetch records where name = "john" OR name = "paul", so basically i am trying to nget all records who have names as john or paul. I am not able to do the same. Please guide.

```
List students = sess.createCriteria(student.class)
    .add( Restrictions.eq("name", "John") )
    .add( Restrictions.eq("name", "Paul")) )
    .list();
```

This is the non working code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
List students = sess.createCriteria(student.class)
   .add( Restrictions.in("name", new String[] { "John", "Paul" } ) )
   .list();
```

PS. I recommend you using QueryDSL than Criteria API.

Comment: Check [QueryDSL vs Criteria API](http://blog.mysema.com/2010/04/querydsl-as-alternative-to-jpa-2.html)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
 Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Student.class);
 Criterion name =  Restrictions.eq("name", "John") ;
 Criterion name2 = Restrictions.eq("name", "Paul"));
 LogicalExpression orExp = Restrictions.or(name,name2);
 crit.add(orExp);
 List<Student> results = crit.list();
```